# Lotus Notes searching two different Views

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

This will all be done on the client. Is it posible to search two particular 
view. This an example of the fields:

ViewName = MyView1 colunm fields are called Name1, Name2, Name3 
           MyView2 colunm fields are department1, Name1, Name2, Name3 .

The Name1 in MyView1 is sorted and categorized while the department1 in MyView2 is sorted

I need the following to happen,To have a View that i would be able
to search the colunm  Name1 in MyView1 and department1 in MyView2 that is having 
both in one, so i dont have to always change from MyView1 to MyView2 before i could
make a fast search

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You want to use the fulltext search in one view to get documents of two views?

Comment: yes. or can one merg two views togther or using the fulltext search to search two first colunm

Comment: Why don't you create a view which contains the documents of both other views? Using the fulltext search you can create a search string like "FIELD Name1 CONTAINS '*xy*' OR FIELD Department1 CONTAINS '*abc*'" and you will get the documents you need

Comment: Am not really sure what u meant by create a search string, but what i want to do is when i type on the view a Find dialogbox pop out so when i type what i need to find in the Starts with field and hit the botten find it should be able to find or search both View or first two colunm for my text

Comment: If you want to use the notes client "Find" Dialog you cannot search in multiple views.

Comment: ok thanks, bus can i search btw two colunm, first two colunm?

Comment: You can search in the first sorted column or in any column.

Answer (score 0):

Type- Ahead searching always works on the first sorted column. You cannot use "multiple" searches in this kind of search. You can decide to search in the first sorted column, or in the complete view, but not restrict your search to two columns.

In version 9 to search the complete view, you just need to change the `search in` parameter in the search window. For versions before that there are unfortunately two different search windows.

The `search in first sorted column` kind of search window can be opened by just starting to type.
The `search in the complete view` search window can be opened with Ctrl + F (english client).

If you want to really "search" all occurences, then you need to use the third kind of search in Lotus Notes, the so called `Fulltext search` The fulltext search bar can be opened using the `View - Search this view` menu item. It only works (completely), if the database has a fulltext index: Ask your admin to create a fulltext for you, if you are not able to do so.

In that search you can use terms to search. e.g.:

```
[Name1] CONTAINS "xy" and [Department1] CONTAINS "MyDepartment"
```

With Name1 = Name of item in document containing the Name you search for (not necessarily name of column) and Department1 = Name of item containing values for department.

`FIELD Name1 = "xy"` is the same as `[Name1] = "xy"`

You can find everything about how to use search strings in the Help of your Lotus Notes Client.